# SSIS package writes empty CSV file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package in SSIS which in a first step executes these two queries:

```
truncate table mytable;

insert into mytable
select * from myview
```

Then, a second step read data from view that takes data from mytable in join with other tables, and writes all the data into a csv file.

The job has never given me any problems, in the last three days however the csv file that is written only contains the header row with the name of the fields.
I specify that the job also does not fail, the execution is successful.

The csv file that is written is very bih, about 1.5 gb as I have to upload it to an application that requires the entire data history each time it is loaded so I cannot remove any data by appying a filter before write the file.

Can you help me?

I've tried to change the timeout options of the first step to 300 seconds (it was 0), the exported file is still empty.

[image: Timeout Settings]

Then I tried to change the contraint option in the connection between the first and the second step
It was "Success" I tried with "Completion". File still empty.

[image: Precedence constraint editor]

Comment: (1) Eventually, do you have data in the *mytable* table? (2) you can turn on Verbose logging on the SSIS run-time server. It will log number of rows flowing through the Data Flow Task (DFT), i.e. Source => .csv file Destination.

Comment: Traditionally, an "empty" file is the signifier that the Data Flow ran and there was no source data. In your case, empty includes the header. An excellent practice is have a Row Count transform immediately after your source so that you can count the initial number of rows sent to a data flow. I would then log that value to an ETL Metrics table so I know row counts for Original + Insert/Update/Delete/NoAction and if the sum of those 4 isn't the same as Original, I'm leaking data somewhere. But that's bigger, put a basic row count in and I expect you'll see 0 logged when you have an empty file